# pgAdmin 4 server could not be contacted on WINDOWS 11

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I'm having what I've found to be a very common problem when installing Postgresql 15 and pgAdmin4. I am trying to install it on windows 11, all the solutions I found are for windows 10 and are not applicable to windows 11.

Most of the time they suggested deleting `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin\sessions` and similar solutions, but Windows 11 has a different folder order among other differences, so here I am looking for help, this is the error I get.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJRwi.png)

Thanks in advance to anyone who takes the time to help me.

Comment: Best guess is you are using pgAdmin4 7.4 as installed by EDB installer. That does not work per this message [pgAdmin](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAMa%3DN%3DN242m0L%3DDKvtuP7hiLX2rU6fHUZqD8fB0Pg3s4PdgYKA%40mail.gmail.com). You will need to uninstall just the pgAdmin software and then download and install directly from the pgAdmin site here [Windows](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-windows/).

Answer (score 0):

Check if pgAdmin 4 server is running.

Temporarily disable firewall/antivirus.

Verify Python path and "runtime_config.json".

Repair or reinstall pgAdmin 4.

Run pgAdmin 4 as Administrator.

Check for port conflicts (port 5050).

Verify PostgreSQL 15 installation and server.

Run this command to restart your pgadmin4 server

```
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\pgAdmin 4\python\python.exe" "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\pgAdmin 4\web\pgAdmin4.py"
```

Also make sure to temporarily disable Windows Firewall by running as Administrator

```
netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state off
```